# Error when using v-bind "is" in Dynamic Vue 3 Componet in Nuxt 3 - Failed to resolve component

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am getting an error (below) when trying to provide the "is" attribute inside an object in v-bind on a dynamic component. I am using Nuxt3.

Error: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: component
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
{ is: 'AppLink', to: 'myRoute' }
Invalid value used as weak map key

Example when used in a component:

```
<component v-bind="{ is: 'AppLink', to: 'myRoute' }">
    <slot></slot>
</component>
```

This is what AppLink component looks like:

```
<template>
    <nuxt-link>
        <slot></slot>
    </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'AppLink'
};
```

If I do it like this, it all works as expected wtih no errors:

```
<component is="AppLink" to="myRoute" }">
    <slot></slot>
</component>
```

Any thoughts interpreting the error would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure thus only as a comment. I think `is` does not work with `v-bind` as it is a special keyword to define which component should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't set your components to global (not recommended).

```
  import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

  export default defineNuxtConfig({
    components: {
      global: true,
      dirs: ['~/components']
    },
  })
```

See the docs on [dynamic components](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components#dynamic-components) about this.